# 4k Photos or just video?

Tags: camera, miui, xiaomi-pocophone-f1

I've seen in the updates that 4k 60fps has been added but I cannot find a setting to take 4k photos. The pictures don't look as good as the videos but I don't know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: If would greatly help your chances of receiving aid if you share with us some basic details about your device - brand, make, model, Android version, etc...

Comment: Xiaomi Poco F1, Miui 10.3.4.0 global

Comment: As for the photo quality, it can be affected by many factors. You might be interested in our sister site, [photography.se] for experts in photography-related thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "*60fps*" should indicate that it's only for video, which is consisted of many (picture) **f**rames **p**er **s**econd (fps).

4K video itself means "roughly 4000-pixel wide". This term came after the term 720p and 1080p for video, which both indicate "720-pixel wide" and "1080-pixel wide" video (the "p" is for "progressive" though, not for "pixel", but that's outside of the scope).

Photos, on the other hand, are usually calculated in **m**ega**p**ixels (MP), which means "the total number of pixels in million". Considering a Camera app usually take a photos in 4:3 or 16:9 aspect ratio (width:height), for 4K-pixel wide, they are roughly 4000x3000 pixels (or **11 MP** for 4:3) or 4000x2250 pixels (or **8.5 MP** for 16:9).

According to [GSM Arena](https://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_pocophone_f1-9293.php), Xiaomi Poco F1 has a main camera up to **12 MP** and selfie up to **20 MP**, so there shouldn't be any problem to take "4K photos". There should be a setting on the stock Camera app to set the MP. Otherwise, try 3rd-party Camera apps that are able to.